# how to query user information by ID using Angular SDK

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, mongodb

I'm quite unfamiliar with Angular SDK and lb-service, and confuse about how to query other's user information by ID inside controller

I want create a friend list feature, and each user only store their friends's ID. The account properties looks like this,

```
  "name": "account",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "gender": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "default": "Male"
    },
    "contact": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "friends": {
      "type": [
        "string"
      ]
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
},

  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ]
```

From lb-services.js, it looks like I can use findById function to find a user, but how to query friend's properties to get each user's information?

Comment: if each user gets a unique ID, just put this object into an array. each index of the array = user ID. after that, give the object an array to sore "id's" of friends, which will be their index.

Comment: Yes, but I mean, how to query user's information based on the ID inside that array? We can get a user's information by "findById" from lb-services.js, But how to create a query function, so I can get every user's information?

Answer (score 0):

to query a user's information based on an index-styled ID, friends being the array containing every user your query function would be:

```
function userById(id){
    return friends[id];
}
```

to get every users info:

```
for(var i = 0;i<friends.length;i++){
    console.log(userById(i));
}
```